# Should be simply "no answer" among bounty reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I am going to declare a bounty on a question simply because I hope it will additionally stimulate at least somebody to think harder on it.

Among the reasons I could choose is "Draw attention", which says "This question has not received enough attention". Now this is not really true in my case, as in a week it got 143 views, 5 upvotes and 4 favorite marks.

So I think one should either add another reason (something like "stimulate more thinking on the answer", don't know) or, more likely, change the text under "Draw attention" to include the situation as above: when the question is  obviously received with interest but I would like to inspire more activity.

Or I just misunderstand the very sense of those bounties?

Comment: It depends on how you interpret that phrase. I guess it can also be understood as: "The attention this question received was not sufficient to get an answer." (So in this sense, if a question does not have satisfactory answer, you might say that it did not receive enough attention.)

Comment: Fair enough; still, in my case, although it does not have any answer at all, and no comments in fact, I would say it indeed did receive enough attention judging from other feedback.

Comment: I believe that whatever boilerplate the software produces, you can add your own text to the reason for offering the bounty.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the suggestion, just did it :D In fact yours may be considered an answer, it just did not occur to me that I could do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that whatever boilerplate the software produces, you can add your own text to the reason for offering the bounty.