# Why isn't "Nobody has answered" on the multiple-choice list of reasons for a bounty?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

When one is asked "Why are you starting this bounty?" the multiple-choice list of answers does not include "Nobody has answered the question." Choosing the answer that says it has not received attention seems weird when numerous comments have been posted, but no answer.

Can this be added to the list?

Comment: A similar older question on this meta: [Should be simply "no answer" among bounty reasons](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3323).

Comment: From what I’ve seen, bounties are mostly used to advertise marginal questions.  Though I know it is impossible to eliminate them, anything that discourages people from using them is in my eyes a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 5):

I am fine with the current wording. Is that really attention, if no one cared enough to write a full answer? Comments in the Stack Exchange system are meant to be a way to suggest improvements to the question, or ask for clarifications. They can become "no longer needed" and disappear without trace, or be moved to chat if the thread becomes too chatty.

Adding your suggested wording to the interface would further normalize answers-in-comments, which are [problematic in many ways](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4841/answers-in-comments-are-increasingly-more-common).